# how to add new set of values with property when json object already exist..using javascript

Tags: javascript

i already have json object..like this,

```
updates={
    mainUpdates:[{id:'1', inner:[{mid:'11',sub_domain:'a'},{mid:'12',sub_domain:'b'}]},
                 {id:'2', inner:[{mid:'21', sub_domain:'c'},{mid:'22',sub_domain:'d'}]} 
    ],
    msgCount:'2'
}
```

now i want add new values with its name(property) dynamically to the existing my json object. using javascrit...
i want the exactly answer is look like

```
updates={
    mainUpdates:[{id:'1', inner:[{mid:'11',sub_domain:'a'},{mid:'12',sub_domain:'b'}]},
                 {id:'2', inner:[{mid:'21',sub_domain:'c'},{mid:'22',sub_domain:'d'}]}, 
                 {id:'3', inner:[{mid:'31',sub_domain:'e'},{mid:'22', sub_domain:'f'}]} 
    ],
    msgCount:'3'
}
```

how i do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manipulate your update object directly something like this:

```
updates.mainUpdates.push({
   id:'3', 
   inner:[{mid:'31',sub_domain:'e'},{mid:'22', sub_domain:'f'}]
});
updates.msgCount = 3;
```

updates.mainUpdates is just a JavaScript array so you can add new objects to it using the push method. updates.msgCount is just a property so can be modified directly.

It might be better to encapsulate this kind of change in a helper method that keeps the msgCount in synch with the array (assuming that is what it is there for).

```
function addToUpdates(updates, newItem) {
   updates.mainUpdates.push(newItem);
   updates.msgCount = updates.mainUpdates.length;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery **[extend](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/)** function (Merge the contents of two or more objects together into the first object.):

Example: Merge two objects, modifying the first.

```
var object1 = {
  apple: 0,
  banana: {weight: 52, price: 100},
  cherry: 97
};
var object2 = {
  banana: {price: 200},
  durian: 100
};

$.extend(object1, object2);
```

Result:

```
object1 === {apple: 0, banana: {price: 200}, cherry: 97, durian: 100}
```

Your msgCount field is redundant, as you can use `update.mainUpdates.length`

Comment: Helped me, loved it more if you've given in plain js